# Custom UIViewController hiding properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode6

**TLDR**

Properties are not showing on a `UIViewController` that I was able to access when working on this project yesterday. This is **not** as simple as how do I set a property on a `VC`? I can not see the properties of the `VC`.

**The Situation**

A custom `UIViewController` (A) pushes to a second `UIViewController` (B), pushes to a third `UIViewController` (C)

```
//programmatically calling a push to the next view in A to B to C, example code from B to C.
EnterFinalHRViewController * finalHeartRate = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EnterFinalHeartRateController"];
finalHeartRate.lanes = _lanes;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:finalHeartRate animated:YES];
```

The `NSMutableArray`, lanes, gets passed along twice. Not a problem.

When I arrive in `VC`(C) the debugger reads:

```
A self = (EnterFinalHRViewController *) @"0 objects" 0x15da40c0
V [0]
```

I have a header file in `VC`(C) that reads

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SwimTimingViewController.h"
#import "Lane.h"

@interface EnterFinalHRViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray  *lanes;

@end
```

**For Clarity**

- Lanes is just an example of one property that is passed along.
- This is **not** just trying to set and access a property of a `VC` across a segue
- I've looked everywhere I can, any more links would be appreciated as well.

**The Question**

Why can't I see any properties of self in the final `UIViewController` in the debugger, how would one fix it, and or any useful debugging tips.

**My Theory**

Since upgrading to a new version of xcode, last night, something broke / xcode bug, and I don't know what that is. I am now using Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d). I am testing using my iPhone 5c running ios7. (I will be upgrading as soon as everything works 100% in ios7).

*Quick shout out to thank all the contributors here at SO and beyond. The help is alway very warmly welcomed.*

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `viewDidAppear` in view controller C. Once it stops there, type "po self.lanes" into the lldb console. What gets printed there?

Comment: @AdamPro13 I am getting `<__NSArrayM 0x14e86000>( object 1, object 2, etc...)` thank you for the tip! I can see now that I can access the properties throughout the class, however they do not show up just left of the lldb console.

Comment: Sometimes that happens. Using "po" to print things out is exponentially faster & more efficient than trying to navigate through the objects to the left.